# Função que faça o $foo[array_rand($foo)] direto

Tags: php, array, funções, random

Existe uma função nativa do PHP que faça esta ação sem precisar utilizar o `array_rand` na chave do array?

Apesar de estar funcionando bem e ser um trecho simples, segue um exemplo simplificado da dúvida:

```
//Declarando um Array com um Array dentro
$array_pai = Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( 
            [bar] => ":)"
            [altbar] => "=]"
          )
         [1] => Array ( 
            [bar] => ":("
            [altbar] => "=["
          )
         [2] => Array ( 
            [bar] => ":p"
            [altbar] => "=p"
          )
       );

//Pegando o Array filho aleatorio
$array_filho= $array_pai[array_rand($array_pai)];
print_r($array_filho);
```

**Resultado:**

```
Array ( 
   [bar] => ":)"
   [altbar] => "=]"
)
```

Existe uma Função Nativa que faça esse processo?

Comment: Amigo, não entendi nada. Não basta colocar código, você precisa explicar o que precisa. Se muitos postagem textos gigantes e pouco código você postou muito código mas não explicou nada. Por favor explique pouco mais ai para gente.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta nem a saída esperada.

Comment: Epa, juro que não entendi nadinha de nada. Dá para explicar melhor o que se pretende obter ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta!

Obrigado pelo toque.

Comment: Você selecionar uma chave aleatoria do array pai e jogar ela em outro array?

Comment: Em outras palavras, fazer um array_rand retornando o resultado em vez da chave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resposta curta: Não.

Não existe função nativa para retornar um valor aleatório do array conforme a [lista de funções de *array*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.array.php).